# K-fold cross validation of scikit-learn with confusion matrix of Keras

Tags: keras, scikit-learn, cross-validation

I intend to display a confusion matrix using Keras while K-fold of scikit-learn. My code using Keras is:

```
import numpy
import pandas
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense

seed = 7
numpy.random.seed(seed)

# load dataset
dataframe = pandas.read_csv("BolMov.csv", header=None)
dataset = dataframe.values
X = dataset[:,0:24].astype(float)
Y = dataset[:,24]

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(16, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(7, activation='softmax')
model.compile('adam', 'categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

y_cat = to_categorical(Y)
result = model.fit(X, y_cat, verbose=0, epochs=50)

plot_loss_accuracy(result)

y_pred = model.predict_classes(X, verbose=0)

print(classification_report(y, y_pred))
plot_confusion_matrix(model, X, y)
```

How should I use kfold in this code? [Here](https://machinelearningmastery.com/multi-class-classification-tutorial-keras-deep-learning-library/) the author is calling a function. I believe that if I do that in my code, the `model.fit()` will be executed twice - once for my Keras code and another time (internally) for the `KerasClassifier()`. I would like  `model.fit()` to only execute once. Help from anyone is appreciated.

Comment: **don't call** model.fit() as you currently do in your code but instead wrap your model in a KerasClassifier() and apply KFold() to it

Comment: @pcko1 Can I write like this: `result = KerasClassifier(build_fn=baseline_model, epochs=200, batch_size=5, verbose=0)` and then `plot_loss_accuracy(result)` so that `result` can be used for kfold validation of scikit-learn as well as confusion matrix display of Keras?

Answer (score 0):

`KFold()` is meant for cross-validation purpose where multiple models are created over the subsets of the entire dataset and discarded after the validation procedure is over. So the `model.fit()` should be called explicitly to create the model for purpose. Both the tasks can be easily done through the wrapper named `KerasClassifier()` by packaging all the details of the model design.